# NSNotification - observer not match

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I use NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playNow:) name:@"PlayNow" object:nil];
```

and Post:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PlayNow" object:nil userInfo:noteInfoDictionary];
```

where self is instance of `@interface MyPlayer : NSObject`

And when I call it works great with most cases, but when i dealloc and alloc back MyPlayer instance i'm getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView playNow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8929150'
```

How it's possible that i'm getting error from UIView?

Comment: Are you removing the observer in dealloc? If not, you should.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to remove the object as observer when you dealloc it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

This happens because when dealloc / init another object, the "playNow" method is called to the deallocated instance:

```
MyPlayer[1] init
MyPlayer[1] addObserver
MyPlayer[1] dealloc

MyPlayer[2] init
MyPlayer[2] addObserver

< POST NOTIFICATION >
```

The notification will call both:

```
MyPlayer[1] playNow:    <-- It is causing you the error, because is deallocated
MyPlayer[2] playNow:
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the observer in dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```